# Fill DataTable with Array

Tags: c#, arrays, datatable

I've an array like this one:

```
    const int dim = 1000;
    double[,] array = new double[dim, dim];

    Random ran = new Random();
    for (int r = 0; r < dim; r++)
        for (int c = 0; c < dim; c++)
            array[r, c] = (ran.Next(dim));

    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
```

Can I fill the `dataTable` with the `array` data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var dt = new DataTable();
//AddColumns
for (int c = 0; c < dim; c++)
    dt.Columns.Add(c.ToString(), typeof(double));
//LoadData
for (int r = 0; r < dim; r++)
    dt.LoadDataRow(arry[r]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to set up the Columns and then load one row at a time using

`DataTable.LoadDataRow()` which takes `object[]`

Check out the example in [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kcy03ww2.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, but you must add 1000 columns to the table first like this:

```
dataTable.Columns.Add("Column" + c, typeof(double));
```

However, the real question is why do you want to do that. DataTable is very ineffective data structure.

Comment: If it is ineffective, could you suggest a more efficient data structure??

Comment: @Pedro77 that depends on what is it you want to do with that.

Comment: you should explain or source why it is ineffective.